# Office 365 SharePoint - Individual File Sharing

Tags: security, file, share

I have been debating with my internal team whether to allow the end user to share individual files or not and have also been talking about the potential problem which may arise due to giving each file it's individual Security and hence breaking the security inheritance.

Does anyone have experience of allowing this and has it caused any problems over the last few years or months.

Comment: No technical problems. Without good governance you will run into trouble as no one has an overview on what is being shared. At this very moment I am.. by hand.. checking every document in the HR department because they have allowed sharing and now the new manager wants (as his her right) want to know exactly what is shared.

Comment: I agree with you but want a lot of feedback from other SP experts.  Take a look at this link it may help with your problem of resetting the permissions:  http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/12/delete-unique-permissions-reset-broken-inheritance-using-powershell.html

Comment: Let them share in One Drive for Business and not in team sites if it worries you.

Comment: Could do but has less functionality than in a Team site...